# Flying from Washington Dulles to Prague on Austrian Airlines with layover in Vienna; will I have to collect and recheck luggage in Vienna?

Tags: luggage, layovers, vie

I am flying from Washington Dulles to Prague on Austrian Airlines (both tickets) with layover in Vienna. Will I have to collect and recheck luggage in Vienna? Currently I have a 4 hour layover but am thinking of changing to a flight with just an hour and 10-minute layover, but I'm concerned that's too short.

Comment: Did you buy the tickets in a single transaction?

Comment: 4 hours are easily spent between immigration queues, walking in the terminal, stopping for a drink / snack, bathroom breaks, or the worse case flight delays.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you bought the tickets together, no you will not need to collect your luggage at Vienna. However, since your second flight is an internal Schengen flight, you will need to pass border control in order to connect. Depending on queues, this could make the connection quite tight.

Comment: Yes bought on same ticket.  Don't want to worry with things being to tight so will leave the ticket as is.  Thank you.